# Why is OpenVPN causing problems with my internal DNS server?

Tags: dns, openvpn

I'm hosting some websites inside my network on a server named **WSS** and I want to be able to access them via my WAN address (using host headers) as well as inside my network.  In addition to running a webserver, WSS also runs a DNS service and an OpenVPN server.

For example, I have a site called http://lights.foobar.com, and I use my DNS provider's API to update **lights**, other subdomains, and foobar.com to point to my WAN ip address.

My router (172.16.0.1) assigns reserved DHCP addresses based upon MAC address to every machine, and WSS always gets assigned 172.16.0.6.  The router also gives clients DNS server addresses of **172.16.0.6** (the WSS box) and **8.8.4.4**.  I do this because I want clients behind my router to use the DNS server on WSS which has records similar to those set in my external DNS provider, except they all point to **172.16.0.6**.  I use host headers on IIS so every subdomain can be matched to the correct website.

My notebook's ipconfig /all is returning the correct DNS servers in the proper order.

When I ping lights.foobar.com from a client, I should always get 172.16.0.6, however, **after** a machine outside of my network connects to OpenVPN, pinging lights.foobar.com starts shows the WAN address.  This problem persists even after the OpenVPN client disconnects.

A nslookup on the client yields the following:

```
C:\Users\MyClient>nslookup lights.foobar.com 172.16.0.6
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  172.16.0.6

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out

C:\Users\MyClient>
```

Yet the same command on the DNS server shows this:

```
C:\Users\myserver>nslookup lights.foobar.com 172.16.0.6
Server:  lights.foobar.com
Address:  172.16.0.6

Name:    lights.foobar.com
Address:  172.16.0.6

C:\Users\myserver>
```

I don't know if it is relevant, but if I repeat the same command, the "server" value cycles through each of my DNS records and starts over again.

Here is the ipconfig /all for one of my router clients:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell Wireless 1820A 802.11ac
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 54-8C-A0-A3-15-63
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4829:6960:76c3:2fbd%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.32(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.240.0.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, August 16, 2016 11:12:16 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, August 17, 2016 3:12:16 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 39095456
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-36-08-3C-54-8C-A0-A3-15-63
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.6
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

This is my server's OpenVPN config file:

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\wss.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\wss.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\dh1024.pem"

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 172.16.0.6"

client-to-client
duplicate-cn
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
status openvpn-status.log
keepalive 10 120
cipher BF-CBC
comp-lzo
max-clients 10
persist-key
persist-tun
log openvpn.log
verb 3
```

And here is my client's config (Note I allow the same cert to connect more than once)

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote foobar.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(snip)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(snip)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>

<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
(snip)
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

Comment: Please don't use someone's registered domain in your explanations. There is a [standard example.com](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761) reserved for this.

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit, did you find the solution by any chance?